# Getting error "Image file or image_id string must be include", Am i missing something? ETSY Image Upload

Tags: node.js, etsy

Trying to upload Listing image using ETSY Listing Image API

I am fetching "image_id" & "image" from front-end part.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
             url: 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/724108136/images',
             qs: { oauth_consumer_key: '*********************',
                   oauth_token: '****************',
                   oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
                   oauth_timestamp: '**********',
                   oauth_nonce: '*************',
                   oauth_version: '1.0',
                   oauth_signature: '*********************' 
                   },
                   headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                   },
                   encoding: null,
                   responseType: 'buffer',
                   data:{
                      image_id:req.body.image_id,
                      image:req.files.image
                   }
                };
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
     if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(body) // Image file or image_id string must be included  
  });
```

Comment: I recently ran into this issue as well.  How were you able to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a few things wrong with this.

1. It looks like you're passing the OAuth info via in the querystring and not in the headers.
2. You might want to bump up your request version.  I have confirmed this is working with "request": "^2.88.2",

`

```
const request = require("request");

let options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/724108136/images',
    'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="********",oauth_token="***********",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1585021862",oauth_nonce="*******",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="********"',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    formData: {
        'image': {
                'value': fs.createReadStream('./temp/abc123.jpg'),
                'options': {
                    'filename': 'my-shirt.jpg',
                    'contentType': null
                }
            }
    }
};  

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
     if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(body)
});
```

`